# Ruby Counting chars in a sequence not using regex

Tags: ruby, string, count, sequence, enumerable

Need help with this code on counting chars in a sequence.

This is what I want:

```
word("aaabbcbbaaa") == [["a", 3], ["b", 2], ["c", 1], ["b", 2], ["a", 3]]
word("aaaaaaaaaa") == [["a", 10]]
word("") == []
```

Here is my code:

```
def word(str)
words=str.split("")
count = Hash.new(0)

words.map {|char| count[char] +=1 }

return count
end
```

I got word("aaabbcbbaaa") => [["a", 6], ["b", 4], ["c", 1]], which is not what I want.  I want to count each sequence.  I prefer a none regex solution. Thanks.

Comment: The question is tagged as regex, but the title says not using regex. Which one is it?

Comment: +1 for interesting mental exercise, though I think regex is the way to go.

Comment: @Cary,  see Yev's solution it is very good. It is very clean and elegant. Learn something new today.  #chunk is a good way to use to group sequences.                str.chars.chunk{ |e| e }.map{|(e,ar)| [e, ar.length] }  you can put it in one line like regex also.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Split string by chars, then group chunks by char, then count chars in chunks:

```
def word str
  str
  .chars
  .chunk{ |e| e }
  .map{|(e,ar)| [e, ar.length] }
end

p word "aaabbcbbaaa"
p word("aaaaaaaaaa")
p word ""
```

Result:

```
[["a", 3], ["b", 2], ["c", 1], ["b", 2], ["a", 3]]
[["a", 10]]
[]
```

Comment: Very nice Yevgeniy, love your answer.  #chunk is a nice method to use.  Save a lot of trouble.

Comment: @Cary, How do you use chunk :_alone.  I don't see anything on the documentations.  http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-chunk

Comment: Nevermind.  Was playing around with it and figure it out.  thanks. "aaaabbb".chars.chunk {:_alone}.map{|n, ar| [n, ar.length]}

Comment: hken27, sorry about the `{}` being awol.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use a regex, you may just have to do something like:

```
def word(str)
  last, n, result = str.chars.first, 0, []
  str.chars.each do |char|
    if char != last
      result << [last, n]
      last, n = char, 1
    else
      n += 1
    end
  end
  result << [last, n]
end
```

I'd like to use some higher-order function to make this more concise, but there's no appropriate one in the Ruby standard library. `Enumerable#partition` almost does it, but not quite.

Comment: That doesn't work at all for me - everything gives me `[[nil, str.length]]`

Comment: @KenY-N: OK, fixed a bug.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do the following. Note that `each_char` is a newer method (Ruby 1.9?) that might not be available on your version, so stick with `words=str.split("")` in that case.

```
def word(str)
  return [] if str.length == 0
  seq_count = []
  last_char = nil
  count = 0
  str.each_char do |char|
    if last_char == char
      count += 1
    else
      seq_count << [last_char, count] unless last_char.nil?
      count = 1
    end
    last_char = char
  end
  seq_count << [last_char, count]
end

[52] pry(main)> word("hello")
=> [["h", 1], ["e", 1], ["l", 2], ["o", 1]]

[54] pry(main)> word("aaabbcbbaaa")
=> [["a", 3], ["b", 2], ["c", 1], ["b", 2], ["a", 3]]

[57] pry(main)> word("")
=> []
```

Comment: I was thinking along this same line but was having a hard time implementing it.  The above solution by Yev is very good.  Ruby has so many methods and ways of solving things.  It is too much to learn.  I am so happy for a community of people with experience they ware willing to share.  thanks for your work

Comment: I agree - although his concatenates perhaps not well known methods, it is concise and a comment can clarify things. My code above has two special cases and lots of control paths. Unless you were dealing with millions of characters-long strings, the extra memory allocation shouldn't be an issue, and his solution might even be faster as perhaps the methods are implemented in C?

Answer (score 1):

Another non-regexp-version.

```
x = "aaabbcbbaaa"

def word(str)
  str.squeeze.reverse.chars.each_with_object([]) do |char, list|
    count = 0
    count += 1 until str.chomp!(char).nil?
    list << [char, count]
  end
end

p word(x) #=> [["a", 3], ["b", 2], ["c", 1], ["b", 2], ["a", 3]]
```

Answer (score 1):

If the world were without `regex` and `chunk`:

```
def word(str)
  a = str.chars
  b = []
  loop do
    return b if a.empty?
    c = a.slice_before {|e| e != a.first}.first
    b << [c.first, c.size]
    a = a[c.size..-1]    
  end
end

word "aaabbcbbaaa" # => [["a", 3], ["b", 2], ["c", 1], ["b", 2], ["a", 3]]
word "aaa"         # => [["a",3]]
word ""            # => []
```

Here's another way.  Initially I tried to find a solution that didn't require conversion of the string to an array of its characters.  I couldn't come up with anything decent until I saw @hirolau 's answer, which I modified:

```
def word(str)
  list = []
  char = str[-1]
  loop do
    return list if str.empty?
    count = 0
    count += 1 until str.chomp!(char).nil?
    list.unshift [char, count]
    char = str[-1]
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this pattern with scan:

```
"aaabbcbbaaa".scan(/((.)\2*)/)
```

and after count the number of char for all group 1

example:

```
"aaabbcbbaaaa".scan(/((.)\2*)/).map do |x,y| [y, x.length] end
```

Comment: That involves regex though.

Comment: thanks Casimir.  I looked at using your regex solution.  Trying to see if I can solve it without using regex.  Very nice snippet of code thought.  :)

Comment: @hken27 You are not trying to see if you can solve it, you are trying to see if someone solves it for you. Why can't you use regex?

Comment: @sawa, isn't that the point of asking for help when you are stumped?  Tried search for help but didn't see anything.  I did solve this with regex before i posted.  I am trying to find alternatives.