# How to compress string using counts of repeated character in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I have a function like this

```
def string_compressor(string)
end
```

which receives a string of repeated words and returns the compressed string.
For example: If I pass `aaabbbccaa` it should return `a3b3c2a2`.
I have tried a lot to solve this. Anybody can you help me to solve this?

Comment: You can also try this solution [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19969621/6397542). Just need to convert array into string :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [gsub](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/String.html#method-i-gsub) with a capturing group and a block :

```
p 'aaabbbccaaz'.gsub(/(.)\1+/) { |x| "#{Regexp.last_match(1)}#{x.size}" }
# => "a3b3c2a2z"
```

Or chunk :

```
p 'aaabbbccaaz'.chars.chunk{|x| x}.map{|x, xx| xx.size > 1 ? "#{x}#{xx.size}" : x}.join
# => "a3b3c2a2z"
```

Comment: Thank you @Eric! It works but the code looks complex. Can we make easier than this. If I need the output `a2b1c2a3` of the string `aabccaaa`, what should I do? In this solution `b1`  will  appears `b`  as `a2bc2a3`.

Comment: @Achyut try this `p 'aaabbbccaaz'.chars.chunk{|x| x}.map{|(e,ar)| "#{e}#{ar.length}" }.join`, reference from this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19969621/6397542) without regex. :)

Comment: @Achyut: It's a feature, not a bug. If you want to compress the string, leave `b` as `b`, not `b1`.

Comment: Refactoring suggestion: in your second example you can write `chunk(&:itself)` and drop the `to_a`.

Comment: I wrote it on Ruby 2.0, no `:itself` available. Thanks for `to_a`, though, that was a debugging rest.